# Wrong result when splitting text by '-'

Tags: python, string, split

I need to parse this text.

When given a text for example:

```
line = "1,2,3–7,2,4–2,2,5-6,2,6-3,3,3–5,3,4–4,3,5"
```

I want this result after using the split method:

```
['1,2,3', '7,2,4', '2,2,5', '6,2,6', '3,3,3', '5,3,4', '4,3,5']
```

When trying this:

```
line.split('-')
```

I get this result:

```
['1,2,3\xe2\x80\x937,2,4\xe2\x80\x932,2,5', '6,2,6', '3,3,3\xe2\x80\x935,3,4\xe2\x80\x934,3,5']
```

What should I do?

Comment: Your text does not contain only `-` (hyphen) characters, they contain UTF8 encoded en-dashes as well.

Comment: It looks like you have a character that is not  `-` but `–` (html encoded as `&ndash;`).

Comment: Jongware has, I think, nailled the problem. Best solution might be to substitute the en-dash with a hyphen before doing the split.

Comment: Thanks alot its probably an error in the file text.

Answer (score 2):

Your input text contains [U+2013 EN DASH](http://codepoints.net/U+2013) characters, as well as [U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS](http://codepoints.net/U+002D) (ASCII dashes), encoded to UTF-8.

You could replace those en-dash characters first:

```
line = line.replace(u'\u2013'.encode('utf8'), '-')
```

or you could use a regular expression to split on either byte sequence:

```
import re
line = re.split(r'(?:-|\xe2\x80\x93)', line)
```

Both assume you wanted to keep the input as a bytestring, rather than decode to Unicode.

Demo:

```
>>> line = "1,2,3–7,2,4–2,2,5-6,2,6-3,3,3–5,3,4–4,3,5"
>>> line.replace(u'\u2013'.encode('utf8'), '-')
'1,2,3-7,2,4-2,2,5-6,2,6-3,3,3-5,3,4-4,3,5'
>>> line.replace(u'\u2013'.encode('utf8'), '-').split('-')
['1,2,3', '7,2,4', '2,2,5', '6,2,6', '3,3,3', '5,3,4', '4,3,5']
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'(?:-|\xe2\x80\x93)', line)
['1,2,3', '7,2,4', '2,2,5', '6,2,6', '3,3,3', '5,3,4', '4,3,5']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split`.

**Split by**

```
[^,\d]
```

[See demo.](http://regex101.com/r/yP3iB0/9)

Use it as

`line="1,2,3–7,2,4–2,2,5-6,2,6-3,3,3–5,3,4–4,3,5"`

```
print re.split(r"[^\d,]",line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `–` is a `unicode` and `-` is not so if you want to use `split()` you need to do it in 2 time :

```
>>> l=[]
>>> for i in line.split('–') : # or line.split('\xe2\x80\x93')
...    l.extend(i.split('-'))

>>> l
['1,2,3', '7,2,4', '2,2,5', '6,2,6', '3,3,3', '5,3,4', '4,3,5']
```